# Replace strings in a nested list of strings with another strings in Python

Tags: python

list_A = ["0",["0","1"],["2","3"],["1","2","4"],["3","4","5"],5]

I want the list_A rewritten in the format as:
manipulated_list_A = ["AB",["AB","CD"],["EF","GH"],["CD","EF",IJ"],["GH","IJ","KL"],"KL"]

Here,
"0" must be replaced by "AB"
"1" must be replaced by "CD"
"2" must be replaced by "EF"
"3" must be replaced by "GH"
"4" must be replaced by "IJ"
"5" must be replaced by "KL"

This replacement information is in  a list format as
originalstrings = ["0","1","2","3","4","5"]
replacementstrings = ["AB","CD","EF","GH","IJ","KL"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `replace()` and the list `originalstrings` are not needed to solve the problem:

```
list_A = ["0",["0","1"],["2","3"],["1","2","4"],["3","4","5"],"5"]
replacementstrings = ["AB","CD","EF","GH","IJ","KL"]

manipulated_list_A = [[replacementstrings[int(d)] for d in e] if len(e) > 1 else replacementstrings[int(e)] for e in list_A]

print(manipulated_list_A) # ['AB', ['AB', 'CD'], ['EF', 'GH'], ['CD', 'EF', 'IJ'], ['GH', 'IJ', 'KL'], 'KL']
```

If `replace()` is required, you could do:

```
list_A = ["0",["0","1"],["2","3"],["1","2","4"],["3","4","5"],"5"]
replacementstrings = ["AB","CD","EF","GH","IJ","KL"]

manipulated_list_A = [[d.replace(d, replacementstrings[int(d)]) for d in e] if len(e) > 1 else replacementstrings[int(e)] for e in list_A]

print(manipulated_list_A) # ['AB', ['AB', 'CD'], ['EF', 'GH'], ['CD', 'EF', 'IJ'], ['GH', 'IJ', 'KL'], 'KL']
```

although it is quite redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Using a recursive function, and some dict-comprehension, we can create a translation-table, that we can use to replace the values inside of the list:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from copy import deepcopy

def replacer(lst, *, in_place=True):
    if not in_place:
        lst = deepcopy(lst)
    trans = {str(i): ascii_uppercase[i*2:(i*2)+2] for i in range(int(len(ascii_uppercase)/2))}
    for idx, v in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(v, list):
            replacer(v)
        elif isinstance(v, str):
            lst[idx] = trans[v]
    return lst

list_A = ["0", ["0", "1"], ["2", "3"], ["1", "2", "4"], ["3", "4", "5"], 5]
print(replacer(list_A, in_place=False))
print(list_A)
```

Output:

```
['AB', ['AB', 'CD'], ['EF', 'GH'], ['CD', 'EF', 'IJ'], ['GH', 'IJ', 'KL'], 5]
['0', ['0', '1'], ['2', '3'], ['1', '2', '4'], ['3', '4', '5'], 5]
```

This script will work with numbers up to `"12"` due to that being the 13th index, and the English alphabet is 26 characters long. `26 / 2 == 13`.